# Listview with textview, image, checkboxes, and buttons

Tags: android, xml

I seem to be having problem creating an adapter for listview to display items(Stuff on the title) from another .xml class.

> Could someone provide me an example or hints on which adapter I should
>   use? To Add items xml items on the ListView.

I am not generating any new items in anyway. I just use per-existing items from another xml.

Here is an image of what I am hoping to covert my other xml to a listview.

[image: This is the image.]

Reason for doing this is because in the future I want to add items onto my new list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now all the hard answers without consistency aside.

Here is a simpler solution or almost a hack of it and the process of actually doing it.

1. Start Building on a Linear Layout using the GUI settings making sure they are lined up properly. My orientation is vertical
2. After everything is complete copy and paste everything from top to bottom on a notepad and remove the .
3. Now create on a relative layout. Width&Height = Match Parent. Orientation Vertical.
4. Now add in a Scrollview with wrap_content for height and width. Then paste up everything from the number 2 task.

There you go an entire scroll view for your whole view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CustomAdapter extending BaseAdapter as per below code and link
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html

```
public class List14 extends ListActivity {

    private static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private Bitmap mIcon1;
        private Bitmap mIcon2;

        public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
            // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

            // Icons bound to the rows.
            mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.icon48x48_1);
            mIcon2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.icon48x48_2);
        }

        /**
         * The number of items in the list is determined by the number of speeches
         * in our array.
         *
         * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getCount()
         */
        public int getCount() {
            return DATA.length;
        }

        /**
         * Since the data comes from an array, just returning the index is
         * sufficent to get at the data. If we were using a more complex data
         * structure, we would return whatever object represents one row in the
         * list.
         *
         * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getItem(int)
         */
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        /**
         * Use the array index as a unique id.
         *
         * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getItemId(int)
         */
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        /**
         * Make a view to hold each row.
         *
         * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getView(int, android.view.View,
         *      android.view.ViewGroup)
         */
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid unneccessary calls
            // to findViewById() on each row.
            ViewHolder holder;

            // When convertView is not null, we can reuse it directly, there is no need
            // to reinflate it. We only inflate a new View when the convertView supplied
            // by ListView is null.
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_icon_text, null);

                // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children views
                // we want to bind data to.
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
                // and the ImageView.
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            // Bind the data efficiently with the holder.
            holder.text.setText(DATA[position]);
            holder.icon.setImageBitmap((position & 1) == 1 ? mIcon1 : mIcon2);

            return convertView;
        }

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView text;
            ImageView icon;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(this));
    }

    private static final String[] DATA = Cheeses.sCheeseStrings;
}
```

Comment: when I look at the holder it means I am populating a list with 2 generic items on probably a row. What I wanted was more like a transfer between the data of my xml to a listview. I will put out an image to better understand what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is to create a XML layout for a single item of your listview.

Then create a CustomAdapter to attach to your ListView. with getView() where you can intialize the single row data/events in it. you can find various samples out there implementing the same..

Comment: Major difference with mine is just convert it to a listview as I said I have items on my other xml file which I want to put on a listview. I don't want to populate it with new information just preexisting xml. Most other samples shows on how to populate them not grab them from one xml and just displaying them.

Comment: xml is just an empty view.. you can grab View/Design/UI of it (through Java code, by inflating from those existing xml layouts), The data for it: in getView() you have to provide some manner to put data into that...

Comment: True but after inflation requires population. During the population of generic items there will be a difficulty of calling the items from another .xml file to convert it to a listview. I have an image posted up so I can show you what I want converted into a listview.

Comment: Also most of the examples populates with an array. Don't have one. Just the .xml.